# how to know if a device is in use in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I use several ways move a large size of data (commands, programs in background, nautilus) some times these programs notify me that the process end but I see the led of my devices is blinking, and I need to know if the device is still in use before remove it. Is there a shell command to know if a device is transferring data showing this information?

Comment: Well not necessarily, but I guess there you'd get a more accurate and elaborated responses

Answer (score 1):

You should **unmount** device before removing (dosn't matter via `umount` command or from GUI). If there is still data being transfered - unmount will stall until all transfers are finished (GUI may give some error, if it can't unmount within some time frame).

You can also use:

- `sync` (maybe a few times) to flush unwritten data (and unmount after);
- `df` to check if device You're going to remove is already unmounted.

P.S.: `umount` will show "Device busy" if some program still has open some file/folder in this device (usually it is some shell, but You can try finding it with `lsof`).

Answer (score 1):

`iostat` is the easiest way to track how much traffic is going to a disk.  Simply run `iostat` <*interval in seconds*> and it will show you the activity on each device.  Its first output is the activity since boot time so wait for at least the second output.

```
 [admin@centos6 ~]$ iostat 30
 Linux 2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64 (centos6)  20/09/14    _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

 avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
            6.92    0.01    0.41    0.42    0.00   92.24

 Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
 sda               2.64        48.41       247.81    5396088   27622750
 dm-0              1.67        42.88         1.44    4779498     161072
 dm-1              0.05         0.05         0.35       5840      39104
 dm-2             29.65         3.31       236.22     368442   26330928
 dm-3              0.16         0.04         1.28       4610     142128
 dm-4              1.08         0.43         8.51      48194     949032

 avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           94.60    0.00    3.96    1.44    0.00    0.00

 Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
 sda              14.12       122.78      2437.28       3504      69560
 dm-0            241.00       118.01      1901.61       3368      54272
 dm-1             59.88         0.00       479.05          0      13672
 dm-2              0.14         1.12         0.00         32          0
 dm-3              0.18         0.00         1.40          0         40
 dm-4              7.32         3.08        55.22         88       1576

 ^C
 [admin@centos6 ~]$
```

If you want to track what processes are writing to what disk you need [SystemTap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap).  The Red Hat site has a good [example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/mainsect-disk.html).